# Finding the maximum and minimum value of $\iint_D \frac{dy dx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ where $D$ is a unit disk

Tags: calculus, integration, maxima-minima

I have to prove that the maximum/minimum value of 
$$ I(D)=\iint_{D}\frac{dx\, dy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $$
where $D$ is a unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ enclosing the origin, are respectively $\pi$ and $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

I am not able begin it. I need some hint for approaching the problem.

Comment: The $y\mapsto y-2$ shift is irrelevant, so I have simply removed it. Waiting for further improvements before pondering a reopening - the question in itself is interesting.

Comment: I would also add that [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) is really helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming that all the variables are real:

$$\mathscr{I}_{\space\text{n}}\left(\text{a},\text{b},\text{c},\text{d}\right):=\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\int_\text{c}^\text{d}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2\cdot\left(\text{y}-\text{n}\right)^2}}\space\text{d}\text{y}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\int_\text{c}^\text{d}\frac{1}{x\cdot\left(\text{y}-\text{n}\right)}\space\text{d}\text{y}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Now, substitute $\text{u}:=\text{y}-\text{n}$:

$$\mathscr{I}_{\space\text{n}}\left(\text{a},\text{b},\text{c},\text{d}\right)=\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\left\{\frac{1}{x}\int_{\text{c}-\text{n}}^{\text{d}-\text{n}}\frac{1}{\text{u}}\space\text{d}\text{u}\right\}\space\text{d}x=\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\left\{\frac{1}{x}\cdot\left[\ln\left|\text{u}\right|\right]_{\text{c}-\text{n}}^{\text{d}-\text{n}}\right\}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\left\{\frac{1}{x}\cdot\left(\ln\left|\text{d}-\text{n}\right|-\ln\left|\text{c}-\text{n}\right|\right)\right\}\space\text{d}x=\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\left\{\frac{1}{x}\cdot\left(\ln\left|\frac{\text{d}-\text{n}}{\text{c}-\text{n}}\right|\right)\right\}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\ln\left|\frac{\text{d}-\text{n}}{\text{c}-\text{n}}\right|\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x=\ln\left|\frac{\text{d}-\text{n}}{\text{c}-\text{n}}\right|\cdot\ln\left|\frac{\text{b}}{\text{a}}\right|\tag2$$

Comment: hey..  I am sorry.. i actually wrote the question wrongly.. i modified the question... please try to relook..

Comment: @ManojDash Oke, so what are your boundaries? You can use my answer in the end :)

Comment: The region of integration is a unit disc.. but I am not getting why and how there would be a maximum and minimum value of the double integral over the region?? What would be the criteria to have the maximum and what would be the condition for minimum value of the double integral???  Please clarify this...